# Get Display Image from file using Node.js with Dates

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Is it possible to get images from a folder and output them to and html page with node.js based on a data?

I have a folder called Images
https://i.stack.imgur.com/X93w4.png

Inside, Folders with dates
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wDxN.png

In each folder I have images names 1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg, ect.

I currently have this simple write code to load the html page.

```html
var express = require("express");
var app     = express();
var path    = require("path");


app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'));
  app.use(express.static(__dirname));
});

app.get('/about',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/about.html'));
});

app.get('/sitemap',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/sitemap.html'));
});

app.listen(3000);

console.log("Running at Port 3000");
```

I want to get images from the latest file
and output them to my html page:

```
<img src="(latest Image)">
```

How could I do this?

Much Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you want to update the returned html with the latest image, you better use a template system. EJS or handlebars works well with express.

Then, what you should do is to list the folders at your images folder, then sort them and get the latest one. This example uses readFolderSync which should never be used on a production environment, but should help you understanding how to do it

```
const folder = fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, '/images')).sort()[0];
const imgPath= fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, '/images',folder)).sort()[0];
```

That should provide you the latest image on the latest folder, then it's just a matter of including it on your output file